# How to build a program using PythonQt?

Tags: python-3.x, qt5, pythonqt

On Ubuntu Bionic, I've built PythonQt and the examples work as they should.
How do I compile my own application using the build PythonQt I have?

newbie here, so step by step instructions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the following is all that has to be done:

- Download and build PythonQtx.x
- in your apps ".pro" file, **include** the required ".prf" files from PythonQtx.x/build
- > qmake && make
- [linux] LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable should point to PythonQtx.x/lib when executing your compiled app